# Error: during to connect SSRS with integration mode in share point

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I want to display SSRS reports with integrated mode in share point.

But when I set report server url in Share point then getting below error

`The permissions granted to user 'XXXX' are insufficient for performing this operation. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'XXXX' are insufficient for performing this operation.`

I am using windows credential user and have admin permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connecting SSRS with Share point, you have to follow steps in share point
1. Create Service account for SSRS
2. Set Shared database setting in SSRS application

Then you have to pass the Share point URL into the VS project of SSRS under Deploy setting.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a common ommision in SSRS setup is the provision of the SSRS Execution Account. might be worth confirming you have this setup.

[Technet - SSRS Execution Account](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181156.aspx)